# MVC DropDownListFor adding a span with selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

So every time I'm adding a dropdownlistfor using this code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedModule, Model.Modules, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But for some reason while my select box is showing fine it's adding a Span with the selected value shown which I'd rather it not display. Is there any way to make it not display or am I just going to have to hide it in the CSS?

The generated code in the HTML file looks like:

```
<div class="ui-select">
<div id="selectedModule-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">    
    <span class="form-    control">Introductory Placement</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectedModule" name="selectedModule"> 
           <option>Introductory Placement</option>
           <option>Placement 1</option>
           <option>Placement 2</option>
           <option>Placement 3</option>
           <option>Placement 4</option>
           <option>Placement 5</option>
           <option>Placement 6</option>
</select></div></div>
```

Comment: sorry, you have an extra span added to the option which is selected  ? Are you sure the helper method generated that markup ? can you post the relevant part markup generated ?

Comment: can you show a source snippet of the page after render and the markup around the dropdownlistfor

Comment: Can u show pure code rendered by chrome or other browsers? By this way we can see the span values also.

Comment: I've added the generated code to the question as per the requests

Comment: This doesn't look like the code that would be generated from the above helper. where is it getting all of the `ui-btn` code from? I would look above your `@Html.DropDownListFor()` code. IF not something after the page render could be altering it?

Comment: I think your generated dropdown is reinitialized by some js your using in your code.

Comment: Remove the css class `form-control` from your dropdown and see what happens. My guess is the twitter bootstrap library is altering your rendered SELECT element markup.

Comment: Having disabled all of the javascript files one by one and re-enabled them I've narrowed down the issue to coming from Jquery-mobile which is a bit of a pain as I'm using that quite heavily currently

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue I had was with Jquery Mobile, the way of stopping this was to just add an attribute of data-role="none" to the select box and everything was golden.